# How to use ThreadLocal in scala?

Tags: scala, thread-safety

I am currently this code to extract text from PDF files:

```
String text = new PDFTextStripper().getText(PDDocument.load(content));
```

I need to run this in a multi-thread application, and `PDFTextStripper` is not thread-safe. I'd like to use `ThreadLocal` to init `PDFTextStripper` only once per thread. I tried as follows:

```
import ammonite.ops._
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper

(0 until 100).par.foreach { i =>
  println(s"#$i. START.")
  val pdfTextStripper = new java.lang.ThreadLocal[PDFTextStripper] {
    override def initialValue: PDFTextStripper = {
      println(s"new PDFTextStripper. #$i")
      new PDFTextStripper
    }
  }

  val content = read.bytes! Path(FilePath(s"/data/file_$i.pdf"), pwd)
  val doc = PDDocument.load(content)
  println(pdfTextStripper.get.getText(doc))
}
```

I have 100 docs, and I am using `(0 until 100).par`, which it is using 10 threads, I think. So, the text `new PDFTextStripper. #$i` should only appear 10 times, but it appears 100 times. `PDFTextStripper` is not being reused. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instantiate the `ThreadLocal` only once, and then use it in your parallel computation. Each thread calling `get()` will create one `PDFTextStripper` and then reuse it:

```
val pdfTextStripper = new java.lang.ThreadLocal[PDFTextStripper] {
  override def initialValue: PDFTextStripper = {
    println(s"new PDFTextStripper") // this will be printed once per thread
    new PDFTextStripper
  }
}

(0 until 100).par.foreach { i =>
  println(s"#$i. START.")
  val content = read.bytes! Path(FilePath(s"/data/file_$i.pdf"), pwd)
  val doc = PDDocument.load(content)
  println(pdfTextStripper.get.getText(doc))
}
```

Some intuition: it's useful to think of `ThreadLocal` instances as *maps* where the key is the thread and the value is the lazily-evaluated object obtained by `initialValue`. So - you only want *one* such map, you don't want to re-create the map (thus losing access to the previous one) on each iteration.